# Recommendations for a good fitness course for a 30+ newbie

Tags: health, rock-climbing

So I used to be an avid runner (though never much good), but after a lung infection I got out of the routine and now just don't have the passion to start all over.

I'd like to get back into good shape again -- and so thought of a course: karate, kickboxing, even rock-climbing to do it (though there's no wall in my area so this last one is out).

What's a good course to get fit, learn a new skill, and get into shape?
I don't mind paying for a course, but online tutorials or podcasts work fine too (and given my schedule are even preferable).

Thanks!

Comment: I just posted an answer that focuses on an introduction to bodyweight strength training  with minimal equipment and an eye towards avoiding injury. you may find it helpful.  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18639/how-to-improve-this-workout/18795#18795

Answer (score 1):

What do you enjoy, or what looks most appealing to you?

Do that.

Doing something you enjoy, whatever it is, means you will be much more likely to stick with it over the long term. If you don't know what you enjoy, try short courses of a bunch of different things. Most will help you get in better shape, and when you find something you really like, stick with that.